# Call to undefined function PDO()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote this php script:

```
<?php

//Connexion a la base de données
try
{
    $bdd = PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Hotel', 'root', '');
    /*ou bien $bdd = mysql_connect("localhost",'root','');
    * mysql_select_db("Hotel", $bdd);
    */  
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    die('Erreur: '.$ex->getMessage());
}

//Récuperation des valeurs 
$code = $_POST['code'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$prix = $_POST['prix'];

//Insertion du nouveau enregistrement à l'aide d'une requête préparée
$req = $bdd->prepare('Insert into chambre(code_ch,nombre_lit,prix) values(:code, :nombre, :prix) ');
$req->execute(array($code, $nombre, $prix));

//Redirection vers la page d'ajout
header('Location: ajouter.php');


?>
```

but it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function PDO() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel\ajoutfin.php on line 22

the line 22 : `$bdd = PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Hotel', 'root', '');`

Answer (score 13):

It should be:

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Hotel', 'root', '');
```

Answer (score 9):

PDO is a class and needs to be served as:

```
$bdd = new PDO('...');
```

Answer (score 5):

it must be this

```
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Hotel', 'root', '');
```